# Coproc in bash script

Tags: shell-script, raspbian, coprocesses

I'm trying to do a simple shell script that will make my raspberry's bluetooth discoverable but i'm facing some issues. My raspberry is running Raspbian.

Running this through command line works perfectly:

```
coproc bluetoothctl
echo -e 'discoverable on' >&${COPROC[1]}
```

But when i create a shell script doing the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
coproc bluetoothctl
echo -e 'discoverable on' >&${COPROC[1]}
```

with the command line "bash test_script.sh", the script is exectued correctly but the state of the bluetooth remains the same.

Can someone give me a hand?
Thanks!

Comment: your `bluetoothctl` is probably killed by a `SIGPIPE` before being able to do its job. Try adding a `wait` at the end of your script (untested).

Comment: ... or `wait "$COPROC_PID"`

Comment: It did the trick, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts exits and `bluetoothctl` is terminated as soon as the `echo` is done, which means that `bluetoothctl` may not have enough time to do its thing. It is likely that the co-process exits due to receiving a `PIPE` signal when trying to write something to standard output (which is closed by the script exiting).

You have two options here (quite possibly more):

1. Wait for the co-process to finish before terminating the script.  You do this by `wait "$COPROC_PID"` before the end of the script.  This would lead to the script running until `bluetoothctl` is terminated by some other means (you could, for example, send the `quit` command to it with a second `echo`).
2. Just pipe the string to the `bluetoothctl` directly:

   ```
   echo discoverable on | bluetoothctl
   ```

   or, using a here-string

   ```
   bluetoothctl <<<'discoverable on'
   ```

   This would casue `bluetoothctl` to terminate after acting on the command. The script terminates when `bluetoothctl` is done.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, I incorporated that explicitly now.